# Who deleted a record?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, audit

Is it possible to audit a Postgresql 9.4.5 database in such way that I could find when a specific record was deleted? I don't know what do I need to have enabled / available for such

Comment: There is no built-in feature. But you can add triggers that will do that for you: http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/ or https://github.com/wingspan/wingspan-auditing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. Data that is gone is gone. This type of auditing is normally implemented by custom code (triggers writing to an audit table or something like this).

Comment: Are WAL files of any help?